# Window title font too big

Tags: java, swing, windows-10, citrix

###### TL;DR

Size of font in title bar of *Swing* windows is too big. How can I make it smaller?

###### Details

Oracle Java 1.8.0_201 (32 bit)

I have a Dell laptop.
Windows 11 Pro (version 22H2)
Processor: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1145G7 @ 2.60GHz   1.50 GHz
Installed RAM: 16.0 GB (15.4 GB usable)

I am using a virtual desktop via [Citrix](https://www.citrix.com/solutions/vdi-and-daas/what-is-a-virtual-desktop.html). Virtual desktop has Windows 10 (Enterprise, 64 bit). It also has 16 GB of memory.

Below is a screen capture of a [`JOptionPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) on the virtual desktop.

[image: JOptionPane (good)]

This is correct and how it should be.
However, on another computer, using the same configuration as described above, it looks different. Here is a screen capture of the other computer. Note that the other computer is the exact same laptop as mine.

[image: JOptionPane (bad)]

The main problem is that the size of the font of the window title is bigger than it should be. How can I make it smaller?

Note that the displays of both computers are the same, i.e. scaling is set to 100% and screen resolution is 1920×1080
Are there other settings that I should check?

Also note that both computers use a dual monitor docking station as demonstrated in this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wad99tLquX8).

###### EDIT

Granted, regarding the screen captures above, the differences don't impact the GUI, however they do impact the main application window, i.e. the application's top-level [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) as shown in below screen capture.

[image: Application JFrame]

I have purposely removed the window title (for confidentiality purposes), however the font size is larger than it should be and as a result, the toolbar at the bottom of the window is only partially displayed and this is the problem. The `JFrame` dimensions are fixed (i.e. hard coded) and since the window title takes up more height (due to the larger font size), it comes at the expense of the toolbar height. Changing the window dimensions – including removing them entirely in order to let *Swing* determine the optimal window size – is not an option. Hence I believe that the solution is to reduce the size of the font used in the window title bar.

The application was purchased from a third party. It runs on thousands of computers with the exact same configuration as mine (as described above, including the exact same Dell laptop and virtual desktop) but the problem occurs on only a very few (less than ten). Also, the application has been in use for several years, initially on PCs. The problem only began when we moved from each person having his own, dedicated [physical] PC to the environment described above, i.e. a virtual desktop on a laptop in a dual monitor docking station.

###### EDIT 2 (15<sup>th</sup> May, 2023)

To clarify regarding the virtual desktop. Via *Citrix* desktop we are connecting to an actual, physical computer and not a virtual computer, hence the display settings are those of the physical computer.

Comment: You don’t control this, it’s supplied and configured by the OS directly

Comment: @MadProgrammer as stated in the question, same OS and same configuration on both computers, so why the difference? Note that I am not asking how to fix this in _Swing_ code, I am asking for any solution, including configuring the host computer or OS. In fact, I assume that there is something different in the configurations of the two computers but I don't know where to look, hence the question in my post, namely: _Are there other settings that I should check?_

Comment: There must be a difference between platforms, perhaps dpi scaling - the question is, why does it matter

Comment: _The JFrame dimensions are fixed_ .. nice example why that's a don't ;) Curious: why the different sizes of the first screenshots - artefact caused by grabbing them or real?

Comment: @MadProgrammer you wrote in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76224619/window-title-font-too-big#comment134421479_76224619): _perhaps dpi scaling_ Do you mean like what is described [here](https://knowledgebase.constantcontact.com/articles/KnowledgeBase/6167-how-dpi-can-affect-images-in-emails?lang=en_US)? If yes then they say that _Choosing a display appearance of ... "100%" yields the best results_ I did mention, in my post, that both computers have the scaling set to 100%.

Comment: @kleopatra _nice example why that's a don't_ I definitely agree, however we purchased the application from a third party and consequently we cannot change fixed, `JFrame` dimensions.

Comment: hehe .. then you have at least somebody to point fingers at <g>

Comment: To the commenters: If you cannot answer the question, there is no need to deride it.

Comment: what do you mean? my first was the usual you-get-what-you-asked-for-by-hardcoding (now meaning _you_ get what _others_ asked) and the second was a sympathetic chuckle - so where do you see any derision? Anyway, definitely not intended. BTW: you didn't answer the question in my first comment - if the different sizing is actual it might give you a hook for digging deeper. Actually, I don't think it's answerable from afar, too many flying bullets .. plus you might be (or not ;) too focused on changing the font

Comment: @kleopatra _artefact caused by grabbing them or real?_ Real. Also: _if the different sizing is actual it might give you a hook for digging deeper_ Care to expand on how to go about _digging deeper_?

Comment: okay, then what's causing the size difference? I don't know and don't know what could be the reason/s - but that's what I would try to understand. Anyway, good luck, I'm off now.

Comment: @kleopatra _but that's what I would try to understand_ Exactly why I posted the question. I don't know where else to look.

Comment: Check all the accessibility options on the Windows PCs with large title fonts.  In Windows 10 on the Display panel, you can make the system font bigger as well as increase the display magnification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I found to resolve the problem.

1. Right click on the desktop (of the physical computer that is displayed as a *Citrix* virtual desktop) and select *Display Settings* from the menu.

[image: desktop menu]

2. In the *Display Settings* window, click on *Advanced display settings*.

[image: Display Settings]

3. In the *Advanced display settings* window click on *Advanced sizing of text and other items*.

[image: Advanced display settings]

4. In the *Display* window, select a smaller size for *Title bars*.
   (I selected 8.)

[image: Display]

The result is that the title bar of the [*Swing*] `JFrame` has less height which results in the toolbar not being cut off.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, if you go to the bottom left and type "ease of access display settings", you'll get the following settings page:

[image: Display]

Make sure the "Make text bigger" is all the way to the left.

Let me know if this is similar in Windows 11.

Comment: You wrote: _Make sure the "Make text bigger" is all the way to the left._ It is, so that is not the problem. Thanks anyway.